# Javascript date comparison bug?

Tags: javascript, validation

Why doesn't this work right?

```js
function test() { 
    var start = new Date(2012, 3, 31, 19, 0, 0); // 3/31/2012 7:00 PM
    var end = new Date(2012, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0);     // 4/01/2012 1:00 AM

    if (end < start)
        console.log("oops!");
    else
        console.log("works!");
}
```

Output:

> oops!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Date Object Comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606798/javascript-date-object-comparison)

Comment: Why is this a bug? Your start is actually after your end given the dates you've created. 3 is April, which only has 30 days, but you've set the date to 31, which makes it May. Months use a 0 index.

Comment: @AdrianIftode - No, 3 is for April - Months are 0-based.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Months are 0-based in js

```
var start = new Date(2012, 2, 31, 19, 0, 0); // 3/31/2012 7:00 PM
var end = new Date(2012, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0);     // 4/01/2012 1:00 AM
```

In your case both `start` and `end` are 1 May 2012. Just output the values and you'll see.

Answer (score 3):

Your dates actually resolve to

```
Tue May 01 2012 19:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Tue May 01 2012 01:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

From [Date<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> **month**
>   
> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to see which date comes before the other, right?

When you compare the two you aren't comparing the actual dates you're comparing objects. Try `if(end.valueOf() < start.valueOf()) { //do stuff }`