# Javascript datetime issue

Tags: javascript, datetime, utc

I have a code which stores the startdate `toUTCString` and endate `toUTCString` in a table. 
When I debug the code in console javascript is showing some strange behaviour.

The output in console

```
 var startdate = new Date($("#smdatestart").val()).toUTCString();
 var enddate = new Date($("#smdateend").val()).toUTCString();
 var now = new Date();
 var currUTCDate = now.toUTCString();//current datetime
startdate //starting date
"Mon, 02 Dec 2013 07:30:00 GMT" //in UTC
currUTCDate // current date
"Mon, 02 Dec 2013 07:15:16 GMT"  //in UTC
enddate // ending date
"Sun, 01 Dec 2013 18:30:00 GMT" //in UTC


currUTCDate > enddate //should be true but showing false
false
startdate > enddate //should be true but showing false
false
startdate > currUTCDate // this output is correct
true
```

Comment: Are the values actual `Date` objects or strings?

Comment: whats the value in ($("#smdateend").val() actually

Comment: It is a datetime picker.

Comment: so what are you selecting in enddate?

Comment: $("#smdatestart").val() = 
"12/2/2013 1:00:00 PM"
$("#smdateend").val() = 
"12/2/2013 12:00:00 AM"

Comment: Well, those strings are not in a format which makes them comparable. They start with the weekday, i.e. the order of the strings is determined by the order of the weekdays. A comparable format wouldn't contain weekdays at all, and would like something like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. [Compare the time value of the date objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7606798/218196), not the string.

Comment: where are you from? India?

Comment: Yes I am from India (GMT +5:30)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Date Object Comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7606798/218196)

Comment: The values in `startdate`, `enddate`, `currUTCDate` are String, not Date object. You are actually comparing the String representation of the Date's alphabetically, not comparing the actual Date's.

Comment: check the answer and try the below code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you for first comparing dates in date format. And if condition satisfies, convert the data to `utcstring` and store them according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

```
var startdate = new Date('Mon, 02 Dec 2013 07:30:00 GMT');
var enddate = new Date('Sun, 01 Dec 2013 18:30:00 GMT');
var currUTCDate = new Date('Mon, 02 Dec 2013 07:15:16 GMT');

startdate > enddate // true

currUTCDate > enddate // true
```

Anything involving `'='` should use the `'+'` prefix. It will then compare the `dates millisecond` values.

```
+startdate  <= +currUTCDate ;  => true
+startdate >= +currUTCDate ;  => true
+startdate === +currUTCDate ; => true
```

Answer (score 0):

When using == or != or > or < if the types of the two expressions are different it will attempt to convert them to string, number, or Boolean etc
use below code to compare

```
if ( Date.parse ( currentdate) > Date.parse ( enddate) ) {
    // your code
}
```