# Comparing dates in Javascript and timezones

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone

When comparing dates in Javascript using <, >, =, >= and <= is the timezone used in any way in the comparison?  I am hoping that the timezone is ignored.

Comment: I think this question may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545708/parse-date-without-timezone-javascript

Comment: There is no timezone in JavaScript dates. So *No*, it won't be used in the comparisons.

Comment: The `=` operator you mention does not *compare* but *assign*. On the other hand, [`Date` objects, the operator `==` is not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7606798/2932052).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The timezone part of string representation of a timestamp is taken into account as you would expect, when you convert it into JavaScript `Date` object: the internal value is a simple scalar, normalized to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). So there is no need for special timezone handling when comparing `Date` objects:

```
var d1 = new Date(Date.parse("Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 +0430"));
var d2 = new Date(Date.parse("Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT"));
print("d1:", d1);
print("d2:", d2);
if (d1<d2) {
    print("d1 is less then d2");
} else if (d1>d2) {
    print("d1 is greater then d2");
} else {
    print("d1 equals to d2");
}
```

which gives this output:

```
d1: Mon Dec 25 1995 09:00:00 GMT+0000
d2: Mon Dec 25 1995 13:30:00 GMT+0000
d1 is less then d2
```

[see [online demo](http://ideone.com/Wc6KjE)]

You'll most probably get into trouble if you compare string representations of time stamps.

Comment: Notice that `==` doesn't work on `Date` objects as you would expect

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for pointing me on that [strange JS behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7606798/2932052)!