# How to compare two datetime with same timezone - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone, timezone-offset

I want to compare two datetime of the same time zone in javascript.

I have tried below code but it's not working due to timezone. I can't get a real local timestamp with timezone.

```
var createdAt = "2019-07-28T18:14:46+05:30";
var NowTime   = new Date($.now());

if(createdAt < NowTime){
   $("#sos1").css("background-color","#093");
}else{
  $("#sos1").css("background-color","#F03");
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531212/comparing-dates-in-javascript-and-timezones

Comment: @ShadowFiend Yes you are correct, but I can'g get local system timezone. How I can get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the datestring to date first using `new Date()` function

```js
var createdAt = new Date("2019-07-28T18:14:46+05:30");
var NowTime   = new Date();

if(createdAt < NowTime){
   alert(1);
}else{
  alert(2);
}
```

Comment: Is this will work exact, because data will be fetch each 30 seconds. And every seconds data will change dynamically.