# How to compare two different date formats in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi all I am new to date time things in javascript. I am facing one issue while comparing two different date formats.
Objective- I want to compare date/time coming from the backend with the current time. If time coming from backend is past time I need to do some other stuff or if it is in future I want to do something else.

Issue- Current date format is something like this - `Mon Jan 10 2022 16:38:58 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
Date Time getting from backend is like - `2022-01-03T18:30:00Z`

Code -

```
 $scope.getTimeDifference = function(meetingsData){
            meetingsData.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
                var currentTime  = new Date();
                var x = arrayItem.meetingTime;
                console.log(x);
                console.log(currentTime)

                if(x < currentTime){
                    console.log("meeting is in the past");
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Meeting is in future");
                }
            });
```

Output - Meeting is in future

Issue - Using this code I am getting `meetings in future`, but all the meeting time is actually past time. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you create a new Date from the string the backend gives you, you can compare them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing dates in Javascript and timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531212/comparing-dates-in-javascript-and-timezones)

Comment: @LucaKiebel okay thank you I got it I converted the date coming from backend !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date` will take either format.

```js
const d1 = new Date("Mon Jan 3 2022 16:38:58 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)") 
const d2 = new Date("2022-01-03T18:30:00Z")
console.log(d1)
console.log(d2)

if (d1 < d2) console.log("Date 1 is earlier than d2")

// To find hh:mm:ss difference for the same day we can do this. 
console.log(new Date(d2-d1).toISOString().substr(11, 8))
```

If you want difference in days, hours etc, you will need more code easily found at SO