# Comparing Dates Formated with: "Utilities.formatDate()" in Google script

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I have searched many of the date questions on here, but I am still stumped:

```
for (nn=3;nn<datacommit.length;++nn){ 
  var duedate1 = datacommit[nn][4]
  var duedate = Utilities.formatDate(duedate1,'GMT+0200','yyyy:MM:dd'); 

  var sevendaysfromnow1 = datacommit[nn][9]
  var sevendaysfromnow = Utilities.formatDate(sevendaysfromnow1,'GMT+0200','yyyy:MM:dd');

  if (+duedate==+sevendaysfromnow) { do my thing}};
```

Does not find a match when the same date is in those two separate columns.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is there a plus sign in front of `duedate` in the `if` condition?  `if (+duedate==+sevendaysfromnow)`

Comment: Do you know about `Logger.log()` statements?  That prints information to the LOG.  You can view what the code is returning by choosing the VIEW menu and the LOGS menu item.  Use:  `Logger.log(duedate + " : " + sevendaysfromnow);` to see how the two variables compare.

Comment: I added the plus sign as suggested here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606798/javascript-date-object-comparison

Comment: The logging is cool!  I didnt know that.  This is what I got from the log:      [15-02-06 12:22:47:254 EST] 2015:01:01 : 2015:02:13 Any thoughts on how I format to get rid of [15-02-06 12:22:47:254 EST]?

Comment: Okay.  That plus sign is meant to coerce a date object to a number.  But I think that your variables are converted to a string with the `Utilities.formateDate()` function.  And you should use triple equal signs, not double.

Comment: Those are two different dates, aren't they?  Or am I reading it wrong?.    I'd get rid of the plus signs, and use triple equal signs.

Comment: If you find out that the dates aren't equal, when you expected them to be, then the problem may be higher up in your code.  You should also read the short section on using the debugger.  [Google Documentation - Debugger and Breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)