# JavaScript Date mismatch after being stored as string

Tags: javascript, string, date, gettime

I cannot figure out why `ls_a === a` is returning `false` in the code below. It seems like when I convert to a date to string and back to date, something is being lost, but what??

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6accbax/

```
var a = new Date();
localStorage.a = a.getTime();
ls_a = new Date(parseInt(localStorage.a));

console.log(a);    // Fri Jun 12 2015 22:12:34 GMT-0600 (MDT)
console.log(ls_a); // Fri Jun 12 2015 22:12:34 GMT-0600 (MDT)
console.log(ls_a === a); // returns false!?!?!
console.log(ls_a.getTime() === a.getTime()); // returns true as expected
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicate of: [JavaScript Date Object Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606798/javascript-date-object-comparison)

This is because `ls_a` is a different object than `a` when you call `.getTime()` you are getting a string which isn't compared as an object

Comment: How can I compare them as dates instead of times then? Not possible?

Comment: @Justin you are comparing them as date objects with `ls_a === a` but since they aren't the same object this will return false.  Comparing them as strings or numbers is the best solution in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

There is no type conversion when you use `===`, and therefore, ls_a is not equivalent to a.

> The strict equality operator === only considers values equal that have
>   the same type.

Comment: They are the same type.