# Robust way to compare multiple dates

Tags: javascript, datetime

In a scenario, where the user can select a date (*"from"* date), along with the current date (*"to"* date), **what is the best way to compare multiple** (at least two) **dates?**

Assuming the incoming dates are a string with the format MM-DD-YYYY, consider the following comparison:

```js
a = new Date("02-21-2018")   // user "from" date
b = new Date()               // current "to" date
b = b.setHours(0,0,0,0)      // trim the time to compare just the dates
b = new Date(b)              // converting back to the Date type

console.log("- :", a - b)                            // 0     (correct)
console.log("== :", a == b)                          // false (wrong)
console.log("<= :", a <= b)                          // true  (correct)
console.log(">= :", a >= b)                          // true  (correct)
console.log("value :", a.valueOf() == b.valueOf())   // true  (correct)
```

Clearly there is a problem with comparing it directly using `==`. So what is the best alternative? Would anything be different if we have several (not just two) dates?

Also when comparing two dates like `new Date("02-21-2018") <= new Date()` can a time zone affect the outcome?

Comment: Already answered some days ago. The equality you said to be wrong compares objects instances ; they are 2 different objects so the result of comparison equality will always be false. Compare `valueOf()` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Date Object Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606798/javascript-date-object-comparison)

Comment: @Pierre vote to close, and specify this link as a duplicate.

Comment: Already done see above

Comment: @Pierre a duplicate is nice an all, but how do time zones get into this picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `.getTime()` method on your date objects.
Checking equality on the date objects doesn't work.

```js
a = new Date("02-21-2018")   // user "from" date
b = new Date()               // current "to" date
b = b.setHours(0,0,0,0)      // trim the time to compare just the dates
b = new Date(b)              // converting back to the Date type
a = a.getTime();
b = b.getTime();

console.log("- :", a - b)
console.log("== :", a == b)
console.log("<= :", a <= b)
console.log(">= :", a >= b)
console.log("value :", a.valueOf() == b.valueOf())
```

Here is a similar subject:
[Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

About the timezone,
I am not sure about what you want to do, but :
The method `.getTimezoneOffset()` can be used on your date objects to return their offsets.
As javascript runs in your browser on your computer, I guess the time zone of your `new Date()` will be affected by your "TimezoneOffset".

Comment: any good methods for comparing multiple dates using this method? E.g. `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, ...

Comment: If there are many dates to compare… What do you want to get as a result ?  
Something like the ordering number from the min to the max ?  
I guess we could do something with a `for loop` if we put the dates in an object or array.