# Get date from datepicker not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to show an alert when someone selects a date in the past:

```
jQuery('#date').datepicker().change(evt => {

    var selectedDate = jQuery('#date').datepicker('getDate');
    var theSelectedDate = selectedDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    var now = new Date();
    var theNow = now.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    if (theSelectedDate > theNow) {
        // Date in in the future, all good
    } else {
        alert("Selected date is in the past");
    }
});
```

..and the date field...

```
<input type="date" id="date" name="date" />
```

The problem is that regardless of what date I chose with the date picker, the alert is always 'Selected date is in the past' on mobile devices.

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you inspected the values of `theSelectedDate` and `theNow`? Either through a debugger, or `console.log` them. That will tell you if the values are what you expect. Update your question with those values if they seem okay. Otherwise, figure out why they aren't correct.

Comment: Is this for jQuery UI Datepickeror another Datepicker?

Comment: Comparing two objects directly is problematic in Javascript. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606798/javascript-date-object-comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you do not set the Min Date so that Users cannot select a past date.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#date").datepicker({
    minDate: "+1d"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="date"></p>
```

You can use `0` for today or `+1d` to exclude today.

**Update**

For Native HTML5 datepicker, you can leverage the `min` attribute.

> You can use the `min` and `max` attributes to restrict the dates that can be chosen by the user.

```js
$(function() {
  function nowStr() {
    var dt = new Date();
    var yy = dt.getFullYear();
    var m = (dt.getMonth() + 1);
    m = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m;
    var d = dt.getDate();
    d = d < 10 ? "0" + d : d;
    var s = yy + "-" + m + "-" + d;
    return s;
  }

  $("#date").attr("min", nowStr());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="date" name="date" min="2019-01-01" />
```

Comment: That's fine for desktop, but on mobile it doesn't work, so my idea is the next best thing would be to throw up an alert if they select a date in the past.

Comment: Forgot to add....On mobile the input type is `date` which means as soon as you tap into the field, the device date picker is used and this method (and every other I've researched) doesn't work.

Comment: @user3256143 jQuery UI Datepicker will not work with `date` type of input. If your mobile version was switched back to `text`, it would work. Will see if there is a way to work the date type.

Comment: @user3256143 HTML5 date has `min` and `max` attributes that can be used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
I have shifted now above the selected date

```js
jQuery('#date').datepicker().change(evt => {
    var now = new Date();
    var selectedDate = jQuery('#date').datepicker('getDate');
    var theSelectedDate = selectedDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var theNow = now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
 
   if (theSelectedDate >= theNow) {
   alert("Selected date is correct !!!!!!!");
        // Date in in the future, all good
    } else {
        alert("Selected date is in the past");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY">
```

Comment: This still doesn't work on mobile. Your answer suggests the input type is `text`, which will probably work if the user is manually typing in a date into the #date field, but on mobile the input type is `date` which means as soon as you tap into the field, the device date picker is used.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for the `onSelect` event:

```js
$("#date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var selectedDate = new Date(dateText);
    var theSelectedDate = selectedDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    var now = new Date();
    var theNow = now.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    if (theSelectedDate > theNow) {
        console.log(true);
        // Date in in the future, all good
    } else {
        console.log(false);
        alert("Selected date is in the past");
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<input type="date" id="date" name="date" />
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6471992/10273906)